# knnsearch taking lot of time for large number of features

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, knn

I am using FLANN based knnsearch. My feature-set contains 4 images of size 500*500. I want nearest neighbors to all the points in all 4 images(the query set is same as feature set) but its taking a lot of time to run in opencv with cpp. Is there  anything that can be done to reduce the run-time.
I have set num_features = 500*500 and dimensionality = 4. I want the distance and nearest neighbors for each point in all the 4 images, so the dists and index matrix should have same no.of elements as the features.
Here  is the code

```
Mat features,temp[4];
//input is an array of 4 images that contain features.

int num_data = input[0].rows * input[0].cols;
int num_queries = input[0].rows * input[0].cols;

temp[0] = input[0].clone(); 
temp[1] = input[1].clone();
temp[2] = input[2].clone(); 
temp[3] = input[3].clone();

temp[0] = temp[0].reshape(0, num_data); transpose(temp[0], temp[0]);
temp[1] = temp[1].reshape(0, num_data); transpose(temp[1], temp[1]);
temp[2] = temp[2].reshape(0, num_data); transpose(temp[2], temp[2]);
temp[3] = temp[3].reshape(0, num_data); transpose(temp[3], temp[3]);


vconcat(temp[0],temp[1],features);
vconcat(temp[2], features, features);
vconcat(temp[3], features, features);

Mat query = features.clone();

flann::KDTreeIndexParams indexParams(5);
flann::Index kdtree(features, indexParams);

Mat indices;
Mat dists;
int k = 3;

kdtree.knnSearch(query, indices, dists, k, flann::SearchParams(10));

Mat avg;
reduce(dists, avg, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
```

size of features is 250000*4.

size of dists and indices is 250000*3 and size of avg is 250000*1.

Am I doing anything wrong here? I tried to find but could not get a detailed explanation of the knnsearch in opencv.

Comment: KnnMatching is sometimes slower then Brute Force Matching. It depends on the length of the feature vector. I heard by a length of 32 digits the brute force approach is faster.

Comment: Try it with the BF Approach.

Comment: Actually, I have to only use KNN approach. My prime concern is the time taken which is very much for the current feature size. I cannot reduce the feature size but needs to reduce the time taken. I feel that some changes can be made to speed up the program but I am not able to understand how is it working??